# How to check child checkboxs when the main one is checked using React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I want to dynamically check the childrens checbox when the main one is checked. I found some solutions and other related post on Stackoverflow but they are always using JQuery. I want to achieve that using ReactJS, here is a snippet with my code.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="fullbody" />
<label htmlFor="fullbody">Download the points for the full body</label>
<ul>
    <li><input type='checkbox' id="upperbody"/>Download only the upper body points</li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' id="lowerbody" />Download only the lower body points</li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' id="head" />Download only the head points</li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' id="fullhands" />Download both hands points</li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' id="lefthand" />Download left hand points</li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' id="righthand" />Download right hand points</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

so my question, how can I dynamically check the childrens checkbox when `fullbody`is checked ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this case here you need to have a checkboxgroup and checkbox component. Check the below snippet. Thanks to this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@createnl/grouped-checkboxes).

For your purpose you can install the package and use so that bundle size will be less.

For better understanding, added a div to show the values on clicking of each and parent checkbox.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { CheckboxGroup, AllCheckerCheckbox, Checkbox } from "./Checkbox";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [onChange, setOnChange] = React.useState({});

  return (
    <div>
      <CheckboxGroup onChange={setOnChange}>
        <label>
          <AllCheckerCheckbox />
          <span>Download the points for the full body</span>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              <Checkbox name="upperbody" />
              <span>Download only the upper body points</span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <Checkbox name="lowerbody" />
              <span>Download only the lower body points</span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <Checkbox name="head" />
              <span>Download only the head points</span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <Checkbox name="fullhands" />
              <span>Download both hands points</span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <Checkbox name="lefthand" />
              <span>Download left hand points</span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <Checkbox name="righthand" />
              <span>Download right hand points</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </CheckboxGroup>
      <div>
        <h1>Values</h1>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(onChange, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Working [condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-austin-dz93l)

Answer (score 0):

Try this node package for checking(parent->child) the checkboxes and for hierarchical checkboxes.

`npm install react-checkbox-tree --save`